# AMCHARTS 4 Group Data

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, amcharts4

I am struggling to get the result that I'm looking for while grouping data on AMCHARTS 4.

I have followed the example seen here: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/data-grouping-50k-points/

This results in the following: 
[Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR72y.png)

Both graphs use the same dataset.

As you can see by the image provided, the lower one is AMCHARTS 3 Not grouped and the top one is AMCHARTS 4 and set up to be grouped.

What I would like to see is; the peaks of the top graph to show the highest result of the grouped data. So the section between April 06 and April 08 on both graphs would show the result 150 just as the lower AMCHARTS 3 graph does.

Here is my code for reference:

```js
chart = am4core.create($scope.id, am4charts.XYChart);
chart.data = readingData;

var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0.5;
dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.location = 0.5;
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 60;
dateAxis.groupData = true;
dateAxis.minZoomCount = 3;

dateAxis.groupIntervals.setAll([
  { timeUnit: "second", count: 10 },
  { timeUnit: "minute", count: 1 },
  { timeUnit: "hour", count: 1 },
  { timeUnit: "day", count: 1 },
  { timeUnit: "week", count: 1 },
  { timeUnit: "month", count: 1 },
  { timeUnit: "year", count: 1 },
]);

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.dateX = "created_at";
series.dataFields.valueY = "total";
series.tooltipText = "{valueY}";
series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
series.tooltip.background.fillOpacity = 0.5;

series.groupFields.valueY = "max";

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;

var scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();
scrollbarX.marginBottom = 20;
chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a "max" setting in [`groupFields`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/groupfield/). The valid values are "open", "close", "low", "high", "average" and "sum".

In your case, try using `"high"`, e.g.

```
series.groupFields.valueY = "high";
```

Demo below:

```js
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.data = generateData();

var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0.5;
dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.location = 0.5;
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 60;
dateAxis.groupData = true;
dateAxis.minZoomCount = 3;

dateAxis.groupIntervals.setAll([{
    timeUnit: "second",
    count: 10
  },
  {
    timeUnit: "minute",
    count: 1
  },
  {
    timeUnit: "hour",
    count: 1
  },
  {
    timeUnit: "day",
    count: 1
  },
  {
    timeUnit: "week",
    count: 1
  },
  {
    timeUnit: "month",
    count: 1
  },
  {
    timeUnit: "year",
    count: 1
  },
]);

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.dateX = "created_at";
series.dataFields.valueY = "total";
series.tooltipText = "{valueY}";
series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
series.tooltip.background.fillOpacity = 0.5;

series.groupFields.valueY = "high";

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;

var scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();
scrollbarX.marginBottom = 20;
chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;

function generateData() {
  var date = new Date(2019, 4, 1);
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 2500; ++i) {
    var newDate = new Date(date);
    newDate.setSeconds(newDate.getSeconds() + i);
    data.push({
      total: 100 * Math.sin((Math.PI / 180) * i) + 100,
      created_at: newDate
    })
  }
  return data;
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```